# Rails error with Mysql 2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This error showed up.

Mysql2::Error
Unknown MySQL server host '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I already have the mysql.sock on my /tmp/ folder

```
eldiablo:tmp sbpipb$ pwd
/tmp
eldiablo:tmp sbpipb$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-------  1 sbpipb  wheel    0 Nov 14 17:51 aprm0fjKv
drwx------  3 sbpipb  wheel  102 Nov 14 17:21 com.apple.launchd.1O4gD8GW17
drwx------  3 sbpipb  wheel  102 Nov 14 17:21 com.apple.launchd.xksWCs46sn
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root    wheel   39 Nov 14 17:50 mysql.sock -> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
srwxr-xr-x  1 sbpipb  wheel    0 Nov 14 17:22 steam_chrome_shmem
```

I don't have any problem accessing mysql through the commandline though, and the password set on the db config is correct.

```
eldiablo:tmp sbpipb$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 14
Server version: 5.5.38 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by putting the socket parameter in the database.yml

```
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This fixed it!